# xcversion update`: NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, xcode, xcode11

When downloading xcode 11 with xcode-install 2.6.1, we get this error

> xcversion update`: NoMethodError: undefined method`first' for nil:NilClass

Its a known issue https://github.com/xcpretty/xcode-install/issues/348

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Works for any ruby version manager (**chruby**, **rvm**, **rbenv**, etc or **no version manage**r)

When you call

```
xcversion update
```

1. Get the path of the failing file -> **install.rb**
2. Open it in your editor

[image]

3. Comment line 382

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to comment out the failing call in `install.rb`, however its path varies by installation.

Check the output of the xcversion command to find it:

```
Available session is not valid any more. Continuing with normal login.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcode-install-2.4.4/lib/xcode/install.rb:444:in `prereleases': undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcode-install-2.4.4/lib/xcode/install.rb:379:in `fetch_seedlist'
```

--> `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcode-install-2.4.4/lib/xcode/install.rb`

Open that `install.rb` in a text editor, go to line #382 which calls the prereleases function and comment it out by changing it to

```
#@xcodes += prereleases.reject { |pre| names.include?(pre.name) }
```

(Note: this is exactly the same solution as provided by Ted, but without the flashing gifs.)